# resizing player in django-embed-video

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to resize the embedded youtube player using django-embed-video? Using regular iframe tags, like this, doesn't work:

```
<iframe  src="{{ video myvideo.link }}" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-enter code here`style: none;width: 100%; height: 120px;"></iframe>
```

The docs don't say anything about this, either.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. See the docs:

http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.0/examples.html#template-examples

From the link:

*Default sizes are tiny (420x315), small (480x360), medium (640x480), 
large (960x720) and huge (1280x960). You can set your own size:*

```
{% video my_video '800x600' %}
```

*This usage has been added in version 0.7.*

*And use relative percentual size:*

```
{% video my_video '100% x 50%' %}
```

Comment: You should add some text to describe the solution, and not just post a link. Summarise what is shown in the link. Links can go stale rendering link only answers useless over time.